# How do I use setInterval scope in a coffeescript class?

Tags: coffeescript, setinterval

I am trying to do setInterval inside a class and the code below works fine in the sense that as the car is created a call to its updatePosition is periodically called.

The problem is that I can not get the value of the @currentSpeed variable in the setInterval "scope". Instead I get "Updating position: Speed: undefined" in my console.log when the updatePosition function is invoked by the interval.

When I call accelerate() function (which is called anytime I hit the accelerate button) it returns the expected @currentSpeed value

How can I get the value from @currentSpeed in the setInterval scope?

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
class Car
    constructor: () ->    
        @currentSpeed = 0

        intervalMs = 1000
        @.setUpdatePositionInterval(intervalMs)

    setUpdatePositionInterval: (intervalMs) ->
        setInterval (do => @updatePosition ), intervalMs

    updatePosition: () ->
        # below logs: "Updating position: Speed: undefined"
        console.log("Updating position: Speed: #{@currentSpeed}")

    accelerate: () ->
        #below logs the expected value of @currentSpeed
        console.log "ACCELERATING! CurrentSpeed: #{@currentSpeed}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in doing `do => @updatePosition` to create a callback - because this creates a function (`=>`) that is immediately executed (due to the `do` keyword) and returns the function `@updatePosition`. Thus, you can simplify this to `@updatePosition`.

The fat arrow is required at a different location: updatePosition() needs access to the current instance, in order to retrieve the value for @currentSpeed - but since you cannot ensure that this function will always be called in the correct context, you need to bind it to this function by using the fat arrow:

```
setUpdatePositionInterval: (intervalMs) ->
    setInterval @updatePosition, intervalMs

updatePosition: () =>
    console.log("Updating position: Speed: #{@currentSpeed}")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
setInterval (=> @updatePosition()), intervalMs
```

Comment: This is also possible, but requires one more pair of parenthesis to be valid ;)